# Does a continuous map between etale spaces induce a sheaf map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal F, \mathcal G$ be two sheaves on the topological space X and $F,G$ be associated etale spaces, resp.

Assume that $\phi':F\to G$ is a continuous map (with respect to the etale space topology, of course), can we conclude that $\phi'$ induces a sheave map $\phi: \mathcal F \to \mathcal G$ ?

At first I thought this should be obvious. Let $U\subset X$ be open and $s\in \mathcal F(U)$. $\phi'(s_p)$ is defined for every $p\in U$. Then I can't see how to use the condition that $\phi'$ is continuous.

If this proposition is not correct, what condition can be added to make it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to additionally assume that $\phi'$ is compatible with the projection maps $p:F\to X$ and $q:G\to X$, or in other words that $q\phi'=p$.

Given that, everything else is straightforward.  If $s\in\mathcal{F}(U)$, that means $s:U\to F$ is continuous and $p(s(x))=x$ for all $x\in U$.  Given such an $s$, we then define $\phi(s):U\to G$ as just the composition $\phi's$.  This is indeed an element of $\mathcal{G}(U)$: it is continuous since $\phi'$ and $s$ are continuous, and $q(\phi'(s(x)))=p(s(x))=x$ for all $x\in U$.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that you are using something beyond the definition of sheaves and sheaf maps. Why do we need $\phi(s):U\to G$ to be continuous? Is it because it ensures the commutativity of $\phi$ with restriction maps?

Comment: Well, there are several different definitions possible.  I am using the fact that a map $s:U\to F$ such that $p(s(x))=x$ for all $x$ corresponds to an element of $\mathcal{F}(U)$ iff $s$ is continuous.  Depending on your definitions, this might be true by definition or might be a theorem.

Comment: why does the $\phi$ defined in this way commute with restriction maps?

Comment: Restriction is literally just restriction of functions, when you think of elements of $\mathcal{F}(U)$ as functions $U\to F$.  If $s:U\to F$ is a function, then composing with $\phi'$ and then restricting to $V$ is the same as restricting to $V$ and then composing with $\phi'$.

Comment: Thank you! I have to think through this new (to me) interpretation of sheaves through etale spaces.